# Retrofit2: Upload an Image with some Form Data-Android

Tags: android, json, image, retrofit, retrofit2

[image: The PostMan screenshot]

The above screenshot contain the Post method and Response from the server..
here i am trying to upload an image with some data to my server(catch the image from gallery or camera)..

I am trying to achieve this via retrofit2. 
trying some methods from Internet... but i can't get the right way to done it

new in retrofit2. so I cant done this.

> How to Create retrofit2 interface  and handle the response.. 
>   please help
>
> Edit My Try

Code in Activity

```
  ProofAPI service =  retrofit.create(ProofAPI.class);
        File file=new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+fNameAd);
        MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("proof", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));

 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("userId", user_id);
        map.put("proofDocId", idproofno);
        map.put("proofFilename", proofFilename);
        map.put("docType", docType);
    Call<ProofResp> call = service.uploadFileWithPartMap(map,filePart);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ProofResp>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProofResp> call, Response<ProofResp> response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProofResp> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fjkds",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

> Retofit2 Interface -> ProofAPI

```
@Multipart
    @POST("rest-proof-upload")
    Call<ProofResp> uploadFileWithPartMap(
            @PartMap() Map<String, String> partMap,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part file
    );
```

> and I get the failure message. Is this the right way .. 
>   Anyone please explain the correct way to achive it.

Comment: Check retrofit tutorial

Comment: try so many tutorials.. but getting failure

Comment: What failure ??

Comment: Just edit question with my try to achive it.. please review.. Now I am getting onFailure's toast message

Comment: Check your form data. Must be sure it should be _image/*_

Comment: yes , here is the code :  MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("proof", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done something like below :--

My interface

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("your_path")
    Call<ProofResp> uploadFileWithPartMap(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params,
    @Part("profile_pic\"; filename=\"image.jpeg\"") RequestBody file);
```

Now I am creating partmap like below

```
 HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("userId", toRequestBody(userId));
```

My RequestBody function is below :--

```
public RequestBody toRequestBody(String value) {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);
    return body;
}
```

Now the for the image part

```
RequestBody file=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"),
createTempFile(your_bitmap));
```

Now the createTempFile funtion

```
private File createTempFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File file = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "_image.jpeg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
//write the bytes in file

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Now send this **file** and **map** to your `interface` and you will get the response.Hope this above idea will help you to solve your problem.